# Is there a way to fail compilation if an access modifier is not specified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is there any way to configure a solution to fail compilation if an object does not specify an access modifier?

Comment: why should fail?

Comment: Simple answer: yes, Whrite your own compiler.

Comment: The reason for wanting to do so was to ensure that an access modifier is explicitly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify an access modifier the compiler assumes the standard access modifier. For example:

```
namespace SomeApplication
{
    // This class is internal by default.
    class SomeClass
    {
        //Members are private by default.
    }
}

class JustSomeClass
{
    // All members are private by default.
    int ThisFieldIsPrivate;
    private int SoIsThisOne;
    public int FinallySomethingPublic;
}

// Struct
struct JustSomeStructure
{
    int TypicalPrivateMember;
}
```

Like [HimBromBeere said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515651/is-there-a-way-to-fail-compilation-if-an-access-modifier-is-not-specified/43515768#comment74084443_43515651), it is possible, but you'll have to write your own compiler if you want to change this standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a "target" or a "task" and edit your project file to execute it during build time.

Here you find documentation: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx